# Magento 2 Plugins / Interceptors accessing and modifying $this object

Tags: plugins, magento2, interceptor

I have a plugin that i want to modify functionality of a method within specific class in Magento 2 however am not quite sure on how to access the original object and return the modified data.

### Original Method

```
protected function _initTotals()
{
    $source = $this->getSource();

    $this->_totals = [];
    $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        ['code' => 'subtotal', 'value' => $source->getSubtotal(), 'label' => __('Subtotal')]
    );

    /**
     * Add shipping
     */
    if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
        $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'shipping',
                'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Add discount
     */
    if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount()) {
        if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'field' => 'discount_amount',
                'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
            ]
        );
    }

    $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'code' => 'grand_total',
            'field' => 'grand_total',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
            'label' => __('Grand Total'),
        ]
    );

    /**
     * Base grandtotal
     */
    if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
        $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                'is_formated' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This i have set to have a plugin to modify functionality of method above with di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Harrigo_EverDiscountLabel_Plugin_Magento_Sales_Block_Order_Totals" sortOrder="10" type="Harrigo\EverDiscountLabel\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals"/>
</type>
```

### Plugin

```
class Totals
{

    public function after_initTotals(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ((double)$subject->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0 OR $subject->getSource()->getDiscountDescription() != null) {
            if ($subject->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Offer (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Offer');
            }
            $subject->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'field' => 'discount_amount',
                    'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```

Have used `$subject` instead of `$this` within the plugin, this does not work for me however. How do I access the `$this` object within the plugin to add / overwrite `$this->_totals['discount']` and return the updated `$this` object from within the plugin. I have it working fine with a standard preference but would rather use a plugin if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check this before implementing above code.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html
As per devdocs for Magento2 protected functions can not be intercepted so We can not use plugins for that.

May be that is causing issue in your case.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh ok i hadn't noticed that. I will just stick to a preference instead. Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest where does it say that in there i can't find it?

Comment: Check Limitations in that article. It says Plugins cannot be used with any of the following: Non-Public methods.

Comment: Ah right at the top, i need to stop scanning so fast. Thanks for your help however!